# Dimensions mismatch at output time

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an input image of size 32*32*3 where 3 is the number of input/colour channels. I am trying to convolve and max pool the result.

spatial_glimpse_layer.py

```
class SGN(object):
    def __init__(self, w=32, filter_size=5, num_filters=96):
        self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, w, w, 3], name="X_train")
print(self.input_x)
```

Now in my controller I pass an image to the SGN and see the result.

controller.py

```
import read_data
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import spatial_glimpse_network

data = read_data.read()

img = next(data)
img = np.expand_dims(np.resize(img, (32, 32, 3)), 0)
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        cnn = spatial_glimpse_network.SGN()
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        pool = sess.run([cnn.input_x], feed_dict={cnn.input_x:img})
        print(img.shape)
        print(np.array(pool).shape)
```

The output is as follows:-

```
Tensor("X_train:0", shape=(?, 32, 32, 3), dtype=float32)
(1, 32, 32, 3)
(1, 1, 32, 32, 3)
```

As we can see that input was of the form 1*32*32*3 where 1 = no of batches

Shouldn't the last output be of the form (1, 32, 32, 3) ?

Can someone please help here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is `[]` in `sess.run([cnn.input_x])`, it will return list

Since you only have one parameter, you can just use `sess.run(cnn.input_x)`, then the result should be right

If you have more than one parameter
`a_val, b_val = sess.run([a, b]) # split by it self`, or
`val = sess.run([a, b]) # get a list`